# Failed to connect to bus: Host is down in ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, virtualhost

"sudo systemctl enable --now docker" while running this command I'm getting an error like "System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down"
How can I fix this and I'm new to Ubuntu commands.

Comment: To a first approximation commands like `systemctl` and `service` just don't work in Docker.  Your image needs to be configured to run the main container process in the foreground, not by asking the init system to start it in the background.  Can you edit the question to include your Dockerfile or any other code artifacts needed to demonstrate the issue further?

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to [Latest Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#uninstall-old-versions); Older versions of Docker don't play nicely.

The trick is to uninstall `sudo apt-get remove docker docker.io containderd`, etc... And add the docker GPG key and setup the repository (documented in link). Then install `sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io` instead.

Once you've removed old docker from your Ubuntu installation, you can then go `sudo service docker start` to have docker daemon running without `systemctl` and use `service` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using ubuntu:20.04 Image.

I encountered the same error while trying to use `systemctl` command inside the ubuntu docker container, since **the system has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1)** as the error says so in order to fix that you will need to start you container using this

```sh
docker run -ti -d ubuntu:20.04 "/sbin/init"
```

In fact, running the container will cause an error:

```sh
I have solvedcontroller_1  | Failed to mount tmpfs at /run: Operation not permitted
container_1 | Failed to mount tmpfs at /run/lock: Operation not permitted
container_1 | [!!!!!!] Failed to mount API filesystems.
container_1 | Freezing execution.
```

By default, the container is not authorized to access any device, but a container with a "privileged" tag grants its root capabilities to all devices on the host system that will give access to the container to mount API filesystems and solve the issue.

in order to fix that you will need to

```sh
docker run -ti -d --privileged ubuntu:20.04 "/sbin/init"
```